# Is there a way to move the flagging dialogue?

Tags: support, flagging

Sometimes when flagging a question I would like to look at those parts of it which are hidden by the dialogue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

It is already is movable, click and drag on the top part "I am flagging this question because" area.

Comment: Found it, it is well hidden by having no marker at all :-) thx

Comment: @guntbert [This is possible since last week](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74976/the-new-flagging-dialog-gets-in-the-way/166398#166398).

Comment: @Gilles oh, cool. new feature. It works!

Comment: @maggotbrain [Can we put a border back on the flag dialog?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166392)