# I want to be able to move the "reject dialog" when reviewing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request

The "flag" dialog is moveable (see [my question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6089/is-there-a-way-to-move-the-flagging-dialogue)), but the "Reject" dialog is not, which makes it a little harder to provide useful feedback to the suggestor as to why I reject this edit.

Comment: Yes please! (I was about to create this same feature-request myself XD)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing just yesterday!

Comment: [Edit reject dialog is not movable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173173/edit-reject-dialog-is-not-movable)